# Javascript page not redirecting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a page redirect after a login attempt, but for some reason it refuses to do so. I think it may be the btoa function but I am not sure. The alert section of code works, but not the redirect part.

Anyways, here is my code

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, cname2, cvalue2, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();

    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

    var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();

    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
    document.cookie = cname2 + "=" + cvalue2 + "; " + expires;
}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#username').focus();

    // upon login, set the cookie 
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        if ($('#username').val() != "" && $('#password').val() != "") {

            /*
              -------- Base64 Encryption logic --------
                This is in no way meant to be a secure encryption method, 
                but it is extremely useful for writing obfuscated strings to either a document
                or a cookie file without needing to worry about quotes or characters breaking things. 
            */ 

            // encrypt the password with base 64 (using the btoa function)
            var encrypted_password = btoa($('#password').val());

            // set cookie
            setCookie("username", $('#username').val(), "password", encrypted_password, 365);

            // to decrypt, use atob function
            // var decrypt = atob(encrypted_password);

            // test to make sure it worked
            // alert(encrypted_password);
            // alert(decrypt);
            window.location = "test.html";
        } else {
            alert("All fields must be filled out");
        }
    }); 
});
```

HTML:

```
<form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Enter username here">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter password here">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submit">Login</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: Have you tried window.location.href = "test.html"

Comment: That should work if there is a file called `test.html` in the same directory, check your console for any errors.

Comment: Try `window.location.href` - does that work? @SpencerWieczorek It should even work if not - that would just be a 'file not found' aka `404`.

Comment: @somethinghere Yeah I know, I mean the error (or reason why it's not working) is probably from something else.

Comment: the test file is in the same directory

Comment: Any error in the JS console?

Comment: no errors... really confused about this.

Comment: window.location.replace("test.html");

Comment: Is this part of a form? Could you post your HTML? My guess is that your submit is actually submitting the form traditionally, which means you should change your `$('#submit').click( ... )` to `$('#myForm').on('submit', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); ... })` to prevent the tradional get or post request from occurring.

Comment: added the html to the code window.. does that help?

Comment: Agreed with @somethinghere, I didn't notice this was submission.  If a form is submitting, it will more than likely skip past your js functions because it is trying to refresh the page. 

Also its: 
$('#myForm').on('submit', function( event ){ event.preventDefault(); })

Comment: I'll post it as an answer :) I was trying to get it done in an SO snippet but SO is preventing submissions. @AndrewIce using `e` or `event` makes no difference as its your custom name for whatever is passed in as `arguments[0]`. `e` is easier to use in comments as its shorter.

Comment: Was just basing it off of the example you had used @somethinghere, you used event, before you edited.  Semantics would say otherwise however.

Comment: @andrewice ah i hadn't noticed i changed it. Cool :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should replace your `#submit` click event with a `form` submission event that you cancel. When preventing that kind of event the browser won't `post` or `get` the data like a regular page and won't refresh the page, it will require *you* to do that for it, which means you can set your forward afterwards. So change the wrapping jquery from this:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    ... code ... 
});
```

to this:

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', function(event){ 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    ... code ... 
});
```

I would have put this in a snippet but SO throws exceptions if you try form submissions.

Answer (score -3):

i hope this will help you out..
just save it as a seperate HTML page, but make sure to configure the two variables inside the script..

```
form name="redirect">
<center>
<font face="Arial"><b>You will be redirected to the script in<br><br>
<form>
<input type="text" size="3" name="redirect2">
</form>
seconds</b></font>
</center>

<script>
<!--

//change below target URL to your own
var targetURL="http://***********.com"
//change the second to start counting down from
var countdownfrom=10
var currentsecond=document.redirect.redirect2.value=countdownfrom+1
function countredirect(){
if (currentsecond!=1){
currentsecond-=1
document.redirect.redirect2.value=currentsecond
}
else{
window.location=targetURL
return
}
setTimeout("countredirect()",1000)
}
countredirect()
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: This looks like all kinds of wrong and does not solve the problem. The question wasn't about creating a countdown, but about form submission working incorrectly.